# Cross Platform Floating Point Consistency

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I'm developing a cross-platform game which plays over a network using a lockstep model.  As a brief overview, this means that only inputs are communicated, and all game logic is simulated on each client's computer.  Therefore, consistency and determinism is very important.

I'm compiling the Windows version on MinGW32, which uses GCC 4.8.1, and on Linux I'm compiling using GCC 4.8.2.

What struck me recently was that, when my Linux version connected to my Windows version, the program would diverge, or de-sync, instantly, even though the same code was compiled on both machines!  Turns out the problem was that the Linux build was being compiled via 64 bit, whereas the Windows version was 32 bit.

After compiling a Linux 32 bit version, I was thankfully relieved that the problem was resolved.  However, it got me thinking and researching on floating point determinism.

This is what I've gathered:

A program will be generally consistent if it's:

> - ran on the same architecture
> - compiled using the same compiler

So if I assume, targeting a PC market, that everyone has a x86 processor, then that solves requirement one.  However, the second requirement seems a little silly.

MinGW, GCC, and Clang (Windows, Linux, Mac, respectively) are all different compilers based/compatible with/on GCC.  Does this mean it's impossible to achieve cross-platform determinism? or is it only applicable to Visual C++ vs GCC?

As well, do the optimization flags -O1 or -O2 affect this determinism? Would it be safer to leave them off?

In the end, I have three questions to ask:

> - 1) Is cross-platform determinism possible when using MinGW, GCC, and Clang for compilers?
> - 2) What flags should be set across these compilers to ensure the most consistency between operating systems / CPUs?
> - 3) Floating point accuracy isn't that important for me -- what's important is that they are consistent.  Is there any method to reducing floating point numbers to a lower precision (like 3-4 decimal places) to ensure that the little rounding errors across systems become non-existent?  (Every implementation I've tried to write so far has failed)

Edit: I've done some cross-platform experiments.

Using floatation points for velocity and position, I kept a Linux Intel Laptop and a Windows AMD Desktop computer in sync for up to 15 decimal places of the float values.  Both systems are, however, x86_64.  The test was simple though -- it was just moving entities around over a network, trying to determine any visible error.

Would it make sense to assume that the same results would hold if a x86 computer were to connect to a x86_64 computer?  (32 bit vs 64 bit Operating System)

Comment: I think different optimization flags can make your simulation inconsistent, because the compiler *might* choose to generate different formulas and calculations to arrive at the same results (especially when optimizing for size vs. speed.) Also does runtime CPU floating-point flags for rounding mode and error handling mode (compilers sometimes generate code to set these flags without your knowledge.) However, I'm in no way an expert in this, so...

Comment: For the third question, you should research "*fixed-point arithmetic*". This means that you basically multiply all your numbers by a fixed value (e.g. 1000 or 65536 or whatever; think of it as working with millimeters and milliseconds instead of meters and seconds,) and do all your calculations with integer variables and values. But, you should be very careful about "*numerical stability*" and error accumulation and error bounds. Fixed-point numbers can be implemented quite efficiently, and making them deterministic is much much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help yzt!  I'll definitely research fixed-point arithmetic

Comment: So fixed point arithmetic is basically inflating a normal int, and then deflating when you use the value?

Comment: You might want to (sometimes) use [bignums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) ...

Comment: I second the recommendation to use fixed-point arithmetic; in my experience, getting different compilers (even different versions of the *same* compiler on the same machine) to return the same results for floating-point arithmetic is nearly impossible.

Comment: @BWG: Not exactly, but that's not too far off the mark either. [You can read the Wikipedia article of fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Comment: You may find this useful: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/

Comment: There is a spelling mistake ("experiements") in the question. And the fact that I cannot edit/fix this myself due to a restriction stating "edits must be at least 6 characters" is rubbish.

Comment: java has `strictfp` does same output on different platforms

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cross-platform and cross-compiler consistency is of course possible. Anything is possible given enough knowledge and time! But it might be very hard, or very time-consuming, or indeed impractical.

Here are the problems I can foresee, in no particular order:

1. Remember that even an extremely small error of plus-or-minus 1/10^15 can blow up to become significant (you multiply that number with that error margin with one billion, and now you have a plus-or-minus 0.000001 error which might be significant.) These errors can accumulate over time, over many frames, until you have a desynchronized simulation. Or they can manifest when you compare values (even naively using "epsilons" in floating-point comparisons might not help; only displace or delay the manifestation.)
2. The above problem is not unique to distributed deterministic simulations (like yours.) The touch on the issue of "*numerical stability*", which is a difficult and often neglected subject.
3. Different compiler optimization switches, and different floating-point behavior determination switches might lead to the compiler generate slightly different sequences of CPU instructions for the same statements. Obviously these must be the same across compilations, using the same exact compilers, or the generated code must be rigorously compared and verified.
4. 32-bit and 64-bit programs (note: I'm saying programs and not CPUs) will probably exhibit slightly different floating-point behaviors. By default, 32-bit programs cannot rely on anything more advanced than x87 instruction set from the CPU (no SSE, SSE2, AVX, etc.) unless you specify this on the compiler command line (or use the intrinsics/inline assembly instructions in your code.) On the other hand, a 64-bit program is guaranteed to run on a CPU with SSE2 support, so the compiler will use those instructions by default (again, unless overridden by the user.) While x87 and SSE2 float datatypes and operations on them are similar, they are - AFAIK - not identical. Which will lead to inconsistencies in the simulation if one program uses one instruction set and another program uses another.
5. The x87 instruction set includes a "control word" register, which contain flags that control some aspects of floating-point operations (e.g. exact rounding behavior, etc.) This is a runtime thing, and your program can do one set of calculations, then change this register, and after that do the exact same calculations and get a different result. Obviously, this register must be checked and handled and kept identical on the different machines. It is possible for the compiler (or the libraries you use in your program) to generate code that changes these flags at runtime inconsistently across the programs.
6. Again, in case of the x87 instruction set, Intel and AMD have historically implemented things a little differently. For example, one vendor's CPU might internally do some calculations using more bits (and therefore arrive at a more accurate result) that the other, which means that if you happen to run on two different CPUs (both x86) from two different vendors, the results of simple calculations *might* not be the same. I don't know how and under what circumstances these higher accuracy calculations are enabled and whether they happen under normal operating conditions or you have to ask for them specifically, but I do know these discrepancies exist.
7. Random numbers and generating them consistently and deterministically across programs has nothing to do with floating-point consistency. It's important and source of many bugs, but in the end it's just a few more bits of state that you have to keep synched.

And here are a couple of techniques that might help:

8. Some projects use "*fixed-point*" numbers and fixed-point arithmetic to avoid rounding errors and general unpredictability of floating-point numbers. [Read the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) for more information and external links.
9. In one of my own projects, during development, I used to hash all the relevant state (including a lot of floating-point numbers) in all the instances of the game and send the hash across the network each frame to make sure even one bit of that state wasn't different on different machines. This also helped with debugging, where instead of trusting my eyes to see when and where inconsistencies existed (which wouldn't tell me where they originated, anyways) I would know the instant some part of the state of the game on one machine started diverging from the others, and know exactly what it was (if the hash check failed, I would stop the simulation and start comparing the whole state.)
   This feature was implemented in that codebase from the beginning, and was used only during the development process to help with debugging (because it had performance and memory costs.)

**Update** (in answer to first comment below): As I said in point 1, and others have said in other answers, that doesn't guarantee anything. If you do that, you *might* decrease the probability and frequency of an inconsistency occurring, but the likelihood doesn't become zero. If you don't analyze what's happening in your code and the possible sources of problems carefully and systematically, it is still possible to run into errors no matter how much you "round off" your numbers.

For example, if you have two numbers (e.g. as results of two calculations that were supposed to produce identical results) that are 1.111499999 and 1.111500001 and you round them to three decimal places, they become 1.111 and 1.112 respectively. The original numbers' difference was only 2E-9, but it has now become 1E-3. In fact, you have increased your error 500'000 times. And still they are not equal even with the rounding. You've exacerbated the problem.

True, this doesn't happen much, and the examples I gave are two unlucky numbers to get in this situation, but it is still possible to find yourself with these kinds of numbers. And when you do, you're in trouble. The only sure-fire solution, even if you use fixed-point arithmetic or whatever, is to do rigorous and systematic mathematical analysis of all your possible problem areas and prove that they will remain consistent across programs.

Short of that, for us mere mortals, you need to have a water-tight way to monitor the situation and find exactly when and how the slightest discrepancies occur, to be able to solve the problem after the fact (instead of relying on your eyes to see problems in game animation or object movement or physical behavior.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did some reading on fixed-point arithmetic, but I would like to leave that as a last resort.

Is it naive of me to say that if I rounded all floats to 3 decimal places (using something like * 1000, floor, / 1000) that it would solve the inconsistancies in the calculations?

Thanks for the hashing idea though.  I'll probably write something similar.

Comment: @lzman: Yes, that would be naive and won't work. Besides, it's rather slow. (Rounding to binary would make more sense)

Answer (score 1):

1. No, not in practice. For example, `sin()` might come from a library or from a compiler intrinsic, and differ in rounding. Sure, that's only one bit, but that's already out of sync. And that one bit error may add up over time, so even an imprecise comparison may not be sufficient.
2. N/A
3. You can't reduce FP precision for a given type, and I don't even see how it would help you. You'd turn the occasional 1E-6 difference into an occasional 1E-4 difference.

Comment: I'm aware that trigonometric functions are not deterministic cross-platform (iifc, one developer rounded the results to 1 decimal place to keep consistancy).

Another big one I've heard of is rand(), but aside from trigonometric and random functions, I'm not going to be using any complex math.

Would I still be in trouble then if I limited myself to just these? It seems like there's no solution then

Comment: On IEEE 754 systems (which x86 generally is), `+-*/` and `sqrt` are deterministic, with the proviso that _rounding direction matters_. Random isn't actually a problem, the new `<random>` provides deterministic PRNG's.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to hear

Answer (score 1):

Next to your concerns on determinism, I have another remark:  if you are worried about calculation consistency on a distributed system, you may have a design issue.

You could think about your application as a bunch of nodes, each responsible for their own calculations.  If information about another node is needed, it should sent to you by that node.

Answer (score 1):

**1.)**
In principle cross platform, OS, hardware compatibility is possible but in practice it's a pain.

In general your results will depend on which OS you use, which compiler, and which hardware you use.  Change any one of those and your results might change.  You have to test all changes. 
I use Qt Creator and qmake (cmake is probably better but qmake works for me) and test my code in MSVC on Windows, GCC on Linux, and MinGW-w64 on Windows.  I test both 32-bit and 64-bit.  This has to be done whenever code changes.

**2.) and 3.)**
In terms of floating point some compilers will use x87 instead of SSE in 32-bit mode.  See this as an example of the consequences of when that happens [Why a number crunching program starts running much slower when diverges into NaNs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954139/why-a-number-crunching-program-starts-running-much-slower-when-diverges-into-nan/20960856#20960856)  All 64-bit systems have SSE so I think most use SSE/AVX in 64-bit otherwise, e.g. in 32 bit mode, you might need to force SSE with something like `-mfpmath=sse and -msse2`.

But if you want a more compatible version of GCC on windows then I would used MingGW-w64 for 32-bit (aka MinGW-w32) or MinGW-w64 in 64bit .  This is [not the same thing as MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW#MinGW-w64) (aka mingw32).  The projects have diverged.  MinGW depends on `MSVCRT` (the MSVC C runtime library) and MinGW-w64 does not. The Qt project has a pretty good description of MinGW-w64 and installiation. http://qt-project.org/wiki/MinGW-64-bit

You might also want to consider writing a CPU dispatcher [cpu dispatcher for visual studio for AVX and SSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406658/cpu-dispatcher-for-visual-studio-for-avx-and-sse).