# How to ensure same floating-point behavior on windows and linux?

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, mingw

I have a software that does massive calculations on doubles and it has to run on linux and windows. I do not care about what behavior is used (faster is better), but it is mandatory that I get the same results on both platform.

I am compiling with x86_64-w64-mingw32 gcc version 4.9.2 on windows 10.
And x86_64-linux-gnu gcc 4.9.3 on xubuntu.

I've tried using the following compile options:
  -frounding-math
  -fno-rounding-math
  -ffloat-store
on both systems and nothing seems to work.

I know a bit about the complexity of floating-point representation but should it really be that hard to force the same behavior for a software that has to be cross platform?

Comment: "nothing seems to work". Could you show some code?

Comment: What exactly is behaving differently?

Comment: No I cannot, sorry but code here isn't really relevant or reliable due to the size of the software and the number of calculations. With 3 days of digging I think it most likely comes from rounding and calculation precisions

Comment: Have you considered integer math?  or gmp signed integers?

Comment: I cant work on integers; although i'll take a look a gmp.
For the same code running I don't have the same output on both systems

Comment: Maybe try [checking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5777610/1460794) if all your platforms use ieee 754

Comment: You have not mentioned [this very relevant flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Platform Floating Point Consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963419/cross-platform-floating-point-consistency)

Comment: What are your compilation flags? Are your inputs exactly the same? Are you using some external libraries? How much you results differ on both platforms?

Comment: You might also want to look at https://gmplib.org/, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html, or similar multiple precision libraries (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) if you care about reproducibility and not about performance.

Comment: Compiler flags are -std=c++11 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -fexceptions
So, not much
The outputs are large because the software loops over the calculations and give results each time but the first difference that occurs is a 0.0000012 difference. After 300 iteration I have a difference too large to be ignored by my company's clients.

Comment: yes both platforms use IEEE 754

Comment: @RichardCritten: The C++ standard specifies the order of evaluation in the [expr] clause. It does not fully determine the precision used for floating-point evaluation.

Comment: @wally: Certainly this question is similar. Unfortunately, as floating-point behavior is not fully standardized, an answer for one set of compilers is not a duplicate of an answer for another set of compilers, even if they differ only in which versions they are. Getting deterministic behavior requires, among other things, setting certain compiler switches.

Comment: Do you call any math library routines, such as `sin` or `log`? Do you have any multi-threading or other non-deterministic behavior in your program, aside from the floating-point?

Comment: No multi threading but yes a few uses of math routines

Comment: @EricPostpischil Why is it unfortunate? The duplicate doesn't claim to be version specific. "among other things" could mean anything.

Comment: @wally: It is unfortunate because another question that is generic or that answers for other compilers or versions does not answer this question. And hence this question should not be marked as a duplicate of the other, since it is not a duplicate and is not answered by the other.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This is not a version specific problem.

Comment: @wally: It is a version-specific problem because solutions that work in one compiler version may not work in another version, due to changing behaviors between versions. Or there may have been no solution in a previous version (e.g., because the compiler did not offer a switch to select what precision was used in evaluating floating-point expressions) but there is in a later version (because a switch was added).

Answer (score 1):

To have the same behavior, at least you have to:

1- standardize your type, do not switch from double to long double
use only unique type long double for example 
2- if you have any constante, use floating point literal related to your type:

If you choose long double, your constante must have as suffixe l or L
ex: 0.5L

Comment: I only use double and I take all my data I work on from files, so no constants

Comment: This answer is not nearly sufficient. Differences in floating-point behavior arise from compilers opting to use more precision (e.g. using `long double` calculations even when the type of the operands is `double`), compilers contracting expressions (replacing `a*b+c` with `fma(a, b, c)`), and otherwise taking license with floating-point arithmetic. Additionally, if a program is multithreading or otherwise non-deterministic in its execution, floating-point results may vary. Answering the question requires addressing specific compiler characteristics.

Comment: I need 8-9 digits precision, and the first inconsistency that arises is at 10^-6

Comment: You have to trace where in your program you notice the beginning of inconsistency. It would be due to a particular computation or user-defined function. Otherwise try long double and notice the first inconsistency, it should be less than 10 digits precision

Comment: The first inconsistency happens on the 12-13 digits but after 300 iteration I have a 15% difference on the final result (the approximations errors causes the program to go into if statement at different times on different systems). I need 10^-6 precision. A